# Tkinter - resizing widget containing other widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build UI that look as

```
------------------------------| s |
Label-1 | Canvas-1            | c |
------------------------------| r |
Label-2 | Canvas-2            | o |
------------------------------| l |
Label-3 | Canvas-3            | l |
------------------------------|   |
 . . .                        | Y |
Label-n | Canvas-n            |   |
------------------------------|   |
        | scrollbar-horizontal|   |
------------------------------|   |
```

With the code posted below, I am able to do it. The only thing that I am missing is an ability to resize the part with `Canvas` objects *and* at the same time maintain the functionality of y-scroll-bar. I found a way to enable resizing by uncommenting `self.frame.pack(expand=True, fill='x')` but then y-scroll-bar is not working. Also I can have  y-scroll-bar working but then resizing of `Canvas` objects does not quite work and when I enlarge window, I can see a white blank space as shown below.

Maybe it is worth to mention that the inner `Frame` in my code uses grid manager and I tried to play with both `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` to get what I want. But I was not able to make it work.

I would like to know how to get both working at the same time.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.font


class LineData(object):

    def __init__(self, desc, box):
        self.desc = desc
        self.box = box


class LinePlotter(object):

    def __init__(self, label, canvas, desc, box):
        self.label = label
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.desc = desc
        self.box = box

    def plot(self):
        self.label.set(self.desc)
        x1, y1 = self.box[0], 1
        x2, y2 = self.box[1], 20
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="#D1D0CE",
                                     width=4, fill="#D1D0CE")

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x2+100, y1, x2+(x2-x1)+100, y2, outline="#D1D0CE",
                                     width=4, fill="#D1D0CE")


class Plotter(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, lines_data):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.root = root

        self.outer_canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.outer_canvas, background="#ffffff")

        self.scrollY = tkinter.Scrollbar(root, orient=tkinter.VERTICAL, command=self.outer_canvas.yview)
        self.outer_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollY.set)
        self.scrollY.pack(side="right", fill="y", expand=False)

        self.outer_canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.outer_canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw",
                                  tags="self.frame")

        # uncommenting this parts allows to resize Canvas part but then y-scroll-bar does not work
        # self.frame.pack(expand=True, fill='x')
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        self.lines_data = lines_data

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.outer_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.outer_canvas.bbox("all"))

    def configure_xscroll_bar(self):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.canvases[0].bbox(tkinter.ALL)
        x1 = y1 = 0
        for c in self.canvases:
            t1, u1, t2, u2 = c.bbox(tkinter.ALL)
            x1 = min(x1, t1)
            x2 = max(x2, t2)
            y1 = min(y1, u1)
            y2 = max(y2, u2)

        for c in self.canvases:
            c.config(scrollregion=(x1-5, y1-5, x2+5, y2+5))

    def xview(self, *args):
        for c in self.canvases:
            c.xview(*args)

    def create_x_scroll_bars(self):
        self.scrollX = tkinter.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL)

        self.scrollX['command'] = self.xview
        l = len(self.lines_data)
        self.scrollX.grid(row=l, column=1, sticky='NSEW')

    def initUI(self):

        self.create_x_scroll_bars()

        self.canvases = []

        h = 40
        for row_idx, line_data in enumerate(self.lines_data):
            desc = tkinter.StringVar()
            font = tkinter.font.Font(size=11)
            label = tkinter.Label(self.frame, textvariable=desc, font=font)
            label.grid(row=row_idx, column=0, sticky=tkinter.W)

            canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.frame, bg='white',
                                    xscrollcommand=self.scrollX.set,
                                    height=h)

            line = LinePlotter(desc, canvas, line_data.desc, line_data.box)
            line.plot()

            canvas.grid(row=row_idx, column=1, sticky='NSEW')
            self.canvases.append(canvas)

        self.configure_xscroll_bar()

        # for row_idx in range(len(self.lines_data)+1):
        #     self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(row_idx, weight=1)

        # self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.pack(expand=True, fill=tkinter.BOTH)


def prepare_data():
    lst = []
    for i in range(1, 20):
        d = "{}".format(i)
        x1 = (i+1)*20
        x2 = x1+30
        l = LineData(d, (x1, x2))
        lst.append(l)
    return lst


root = tkinter.Tk()
Plotter(root, prepare_data()).initUI()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sort out problem myself so let me share what was instrumental to make it working:

- do not use pack manager and rather use for all widgets and frames grid manager;

  use correctly `sticky` option so widgets are properly placed and expanded;

  use `itemconfig` to change frame properties in function `onFrameConfigure`;

  setting different background colors for different widgets was very helpful to know which widgets are not behaving as expected.

Below is modified working code.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.font


class LineData(object):

    def __init__(self, desc, box):
        self.desc = desc
        self.box = box


class LinePlotter(object):

    def __init__(self, label, canvas, desc, box):
        self.label = label
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.desc = desc
        self.box = box

    def plot(self):
        self.label.set(self.desc)
        x1, y1 = self.box[0], 1
        x2, y2 = self.box[1], 20
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="#D1D0CE",
                                     width=4, fill="#D1D0CE")

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x2+100, y1, x2+(x2-x1)+100, y2, outline="#D1D0CE",
                                     width=4, fill="#D1D0CE")


class Plotter(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, lines_data):
        super().__init__(root, background="green")
        self.root = root
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(index=0, weight=1)

        self.outer_canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="blue")
        self.outer_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="WENS")

        self.scrollY = tkinter.Scrollbar(root, orient=tkinter.VERTICAL, command=self.outer_canvas.yview, background="red")
        self.outer_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollY.set)
        self.scrollY.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="NSE")

        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.outer_canvas, background="black")
        self.frame_id = self.outer_canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw",
                                  tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.outer_canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.lines_data = lines_data

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):

        f_reqsize = (self.frame.winfo_reqwidth(), self.frame.winfo_reqheight())
        c_size = (self.outer_canvas.winfo_width(), self.outer_canvas.winfo_height())
        f_width = max(f_reqsize[0], c_size[0])
        f_height = max(f_reqsize[1], c_size[1])

        self.outer_canvas.config(scrollregion=self.outer_canvas.bbox("all"))
        self.outer_canvas.itemconfig(self.frame_id, width=f_width, height=f_height)

    def configure_xscroll_bar(self):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.canvases[0].bbox(tkinter.ALL)
        x1 = y1 = 0
        for c in self.canvases:
            t1, u1, t2, u2 = c.bbox(tkinter.ALL)
            x1 = min(x1, t1)
            x2 = max(x2, t2)
            y1 = min(y1, u1)
            y2 = max(y2, u2)

        for c in self.canvases:
            c.config(scrollregion=(x1-5, y1-5, x2+5, y2+5))

    def xview(self, *args):
        for c in self.canvases:
            c.xview(*args)

    def create_x_scroll_bars(self):
        self.scrollX = tkinter.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL)

        self.scrollX['command'] = self.xview
        l = len(self.lines_data)
        self.scrollX.grid(row=l, column=1, sticky='NSEW')

    def initUI(self):

        self.create_x_scroll_bars()

        self.canvases = []

        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        h = 40
        for row_idx, line_data in enumerate(self.lines_data):
            desc = tkinter.StringVar()
            font = tkinter.font.Font(size=11)
            label = tkinter.Label(self.frame, textvariable=desc, font=font)
            label.grid(row=row_idx, column=0, sticky=tkinter.W)

            canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.frame, bg='white',
                                    xscrollcommand=self.scrollX.set,
                                    height=h)

            line = LinePlotter(desc, canvas, line_data.desc, line_data.box)
            line.plot()

            canvas.grid(row=row_idx, column=1, sticky='NSEW')
            self.canvases.append(canvas)

        self.configure_xscroll_bar()


def prepare_data():
    lst = []
    for i in range(1, 20):
        d = "{}".format(i)
        x1 = (i+1)*20
        x2 = x1+30
        l = LineData(d, (x1, x2))
        lst.append(l)
    return lst


root = tkinter.Tk()
Plotter(root, prepare_data()).initUI()
root.mainloop()
```